# NetSuite Duplicate Registration eCommerce

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, ssp, suitecommerce

I want to stop a customer from registering two times with same email address. 
I do not know how I can check the client's email address from the eCommerce registration page.

For example, when a client enters an email in the eCommerce registration page, check if the email was previously registered in the website or not.

If yes, don't let the customer register it again and show a message to the client.

Code that check the email address:

```
function clientValidateField(type, name, linenum){
   var filter = new nlobjSearchFilter('email', null, 'is', givenEmail);
   var result = nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, filter, null);
   return (results == null);
}
```

But I can't call it from client side.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a Suitelet that can be accessed externally and returns a true or false given an email address, just call it within your client side code.

Alternatively, I guess you could prevent the creation of a customer record by creating a beforeSubmit UserEvent that checks if the email address exists and just throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

In SCA there is a module called Duplicate Customer management system which is use for validating email address if it's already registered. You can ask your team how to request it. Or maybe you can also send an email to Commerce SuiteSolution team commercesuitesolution@netsuite.com They are the one who provisioned that bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call your code from client side. To check if customer is registered or not, You need to write SuiteScript for that. Please let me know which eCommerce version you are using?  Is it SuiteCommerce Advance 2016?

If yes, then you can write SuiteScript Under--> Modules/suitecommerce/LoginRegister@2.2.0 Make another folder SuiteScript Write Code there.

Then, You need to call this Model in Modules/suitecommerce/LoginRegister@2.2.0/JavaScript/LoginRegister.Register.View.js/ Router file

Within this view you should able to get the current details and need to check with available detail, You can Show message on same page.